# in which order are components added to a JPanel drawn?

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I have a small application that should demonstrate how the opaque property works in Swing.
however, what throws me off is the order in which `paintComponent()` is called. I'd come to think components are drawn in the order they were added (whats added first, gets drawn first) however in this example it appears that `paintComponent()` methods are drawn in reverse order(what's added last got painted first)
can someone explain this behavior, thanks

```
public class TwoPanels {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        // setting layout to null so we can make panels overlap
        p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        CirclePanel topPanel = new CirclePanel("topPanel1");
        // drawing should be in blue
        topPanel.setForeground(Color.blue);
        // background should be black, except it's not opaque, so 
        // background will not be drawn
        topPanel.setBackground(Color.black);
        // set opaque to false - background not drawn
        topPanel.setOpaque(false);
        topPanel.setBounds(50, 50, 100, 100);
        // add topPanel - components paint in order added, 
        // so add topPanel first
        p.add(topPanel);

        CirclePanel bottomPanel = new CirclePanel("buttomPanel1");
        // drawing in green
        bottomPanel.setForeground(Color.green);
        // background in cyan
        bottomPanel.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        // and it will show this time, because opaque is true
        bottomPanel.setOpaque(true);
        bottomPanel.setBounds(30, 30, 100, 100);
        // add bottomPanel last...
        p.add(bottomPanel);

        // frame handling code...
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Two Panels");
        f.setContentPane(p);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(300, 300);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    // Panel with a circle drawn on it.
    private static class CirclePanel extends JPanel {
        String objName;
        public CirclePanel(String objName) {

            this.objName = objName;
        }

        // This is Swing, so override paint*Component* - not paint
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            System.out.println(objName);
            // call super.paintComponent to get default Swing 
            // painting behavior (opaque honored, etc.)
            super.paintComponent(g);
            int x = 10;
            int y = 10;
            int width = getWidth() - 20;
            int height = getHeight() - 20;
            g.fillArc(x, y, width, height, 0, 360);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

From [Swing Internals: Paint Order](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/wzberger/archive/2009/01/swing_internals.html):

**What's going wrong under the hood?**

A container holds an array with all child components. For painting, Swing (more precise `JComponent#paintChildren())` iterates over the array in reverse order - this means the first added component will be painted at last. Z-order modifies the child position within this array. In case that the layout manager makes use of `Container#getComponents()` (as many Swing core layout managers do) there's no guarantee that the array order represents the order in which the components have been added to the container.

Generally in Swing you can specify the paint order by applying component Z-Order (see `Container#setComponentZOrder)`. This method is useful as long as you're using a null layout or a layout manager which makes use of constraints.

The disadvantage of using `#setComponentZOrder` is that it can affect component position.